# How to retrieve Callout_Response XML in VF Page

Tags: apex, metadata-api

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.Profile admin = (MetadataService.Profile)
service.readMetadata('Profile', new String[]{'Admin'}).getRecords()[0];
```

[image: Callout_Response Image]

When this code is executed in Execute Anonymous, Profile information for 'Admin'(System Administrator) is retrieved in Callout_Response in the form of XML.

Now I would to print that XML in VF Page.

Comment: you mean printing the xml as a string on a vf page?

Comment: Yes @Sarath Garimella

Answer (score 4):

The XML form of the apex-mdapi Apex Metadata API wrapper [MetadataService.Profile inner class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/323bc72d764b62d12edba8eeeb1a0cc1a02a4878/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls#L2754) isn't directly accessible.

The serialization between the SOAP XML response and the class is handled internally by WebServiceCallout.invoke. Yes it appears in a developer edition Debug log as a CALLOUT_RESPONSE, but that isn't accessible until the transaction is completed.

The only easy way to access the underlying XML would be to make the raw HTTP POST request yourself. This can be automated from the WSDL, but would still take some effort.

---

It isn't the raw XML, but you might find it easier to dump out the JSON serialization of the Profile if you just want to see the data.

---

To display the Metadata Profile data in a Visualforce page, create the appropriate bindings. E.g. where `admin` is the `MetadataService.Profile` retrieved from the Metadata API.

You can use `<apex:repeat>` for the inner collections.

An alternative approach would be to combine the JSON serialization of the profile with dynamic Visualforce to automatically view all the data. That's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Can you please share some code piece as an reference Example to how to make the raw HTTP POST request from WSDL,

Comment: Actually I should show the data in that XML in Table Format in VF Page...
It would be really helpful if u can share some piece of code for that.

Comment: @Rajesh So you don't really care about the XML at all? You just want to see the Profile data in a Visualforce page?

Comment: Yes...Thats what the End result I need it

Comment: Then why ask for the XML? I don't get it. That's like asking for a hops when you just want a beer

Comment: Actually I thought of getting that XML to page and Parse that to get the content from that